# How to set TabListener to tabs in a loop in Android

Tags: android

I have into an obstacle when doing my Android application.  My issue is that I cannot create an onTabListener for my tabs.  I have three tabs with different names.  The problem is that they all have the same indicator.  In my code I ran this:

```
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            int n = getActionBar().getTabCount();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

This makes a toast saying the value of the tab (for example: 0, 1, 2, 3), but all of the tabs have the same indicator.  I cannot make an onTabListener if I have all my tabs have the same indicator.  Here is my full code:

```
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            int n = getActionBar().getTabCount();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // hide the given tab
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // probably ignore this event
        }
    };

    // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(tabTitle[i])
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
```

What is the issue?  Is there any way I can create an onTabListener using the tab's title?  Any help to this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is doing exactly what you are telling it to, by setting

```
int n = getActionBar().getTabCount();
```

You are only ever going to print the current tab count. I'm not sure why it has been printing different values for you, perhaps during those tests you tried using different tab counts. Either way, replace the line

```
int n  = getActionBar().getTabCount();
```

With

```
String n = tab.getText().toString();
```

That will change `n` to the name of the selected tab, so it gets properly appended to your toast message on the following line.